# "so" or "such" to replace a preceding adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I'd like to know whether "so" or "such" is correct in the following:

> 1. Those actors were not hired because they all looked indistinct or were regarded as **such**.
> 2. Those actors were not hired because they all looked indistinct or were considered / regarded **so**.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: The sentence is unclear. Were the actors hired or not?  What is it that you're trying to say? Were they not hired because they looked indistinct? Or were they hired because each had a very memorable face?

Comment: They were not hired. That's because they looked indistinct.

Comment: Not clear what "regarded as indistinct" would mean.  Thought to have faces that were easy to forget?

Comment: Maybe they were not really indistinct. Anyway, is (b) okay?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I can't see that whether they were hired or not makes any difference to the ***so / such*** choice being queried here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**as such** is a rather clumsy way of referring to the adjective predicated of them, *indistinct*.  Normally it would refer to a noun predicated of them.

> ... because they looked like thugs, or had been typecast as such.

**so**  is used to refer back to an adjectival modifier:

> Because he was *in favor of the amendment*, or at least thought to be **so**, he lost the election.

But you cannot use **regard** in place of "thought to be":

> Because he was *in favor of the amendment*, or at least regarded **so** <sup>not idiomatic</sup>, he lost the election.

But you can swap the order and then it's OK because then **so** becomes adverbial rather than a substitute for the adjective-phrase :

> Because he was in favor of the amendment, or at least **so regarded**, he lost the election.

Or

> A dung-pit, my lord Kassapa, is a filthy place; filthy in fact, and so regarded; foul-smelling in fact, and so regarded; disgusting in fact, and so regarded; repulsive in fact, and so regarded.

<sup>*World of the Buddha: An Introduction to Buddhist Literature* edited with commentaries by Lucien Stryk. New York, 1968.</sup>